# mySql query search and replace

Tags: jquery, mysql, search, replace

Hey folks, I have a field within a table that I need to do a search and replace on, though it's a bit tricky and beyond my measure of querying skills. Basically, the contents of a field may look like this:

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
image4.jpg
image5.jpg
```

I need to do a search and replace that would replace each line with something like:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image1.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image2.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image3.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image4.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image5.jpg" />
```

The image titles are completely random and could be .gif, .jpg or pngs. The table name is "exp_channel_data" and the field name is "field_id_8" and I'd be running the query in phpadmin. Is the above search and replace possible?

Comment: what possible reason not to do it client side?

Comment: The database is part of a CMS. After some version updates, etc etc, running a query through phpadmin is definitely my best and only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can replace line breaks with a closing + opening tag and then wrap the result in an img tag to get the desired result:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data
SET field = CONCAT(
    '<img src="http://www.domain.com/',
    REPLACE(field_id_8, '\n',  '" />\n<img src="http://www.domain.com/'),
    '" />')
WHERE (field_id_8 IS NOT NULL) AND (field_id_8 != '')
```

Comment: +1, I was just about to expand my answer to basically the same thing.

Comment: This worked beautifully good sir! Thank you so much. Much more efficient then the query i was trying to string together :)

Comment: Actually, how would this be modified to skip over any of the rows where that field is NULL or empty?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. I hope your [Regular Expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) skills are up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my Regular Expression skills are not up to date. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. Can you show me a quick dirty example of how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)